# Adding hover color to specific row

Tags: css

If I am targeting a specific row, say the first one in a table, and want to change font color, I can do this

```
.mytable tr:first th {
  color: red
}
```

But how do I add a hover property to the same row? This won't work, would it?

```
.mytable tr:first:hover th {
  color: green
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you put just the first row in a thead container?

```
.mytable thead:hover {
     color: green
}

<table class="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>hello</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tr><td>goodby</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Bravo! You nailed it. I actually use THEAD in this project and never even thought about it...

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
.mytable tr:first th:hover {
  color: green
}
```

?

Comment: Noup, tried that too... If I did not have to specify the first row, than all I had to do it this: .mytable tr:hover th but combining the two... no idea

Answer (score 1):

Surely you use `first-child` and not just `first`? Then apply the hover to the `first-child`. You don't need to specify `th` as it will propogate through anyway.

Check this ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x3bWg/2/)***

```
.mytable tr:first-child { color: red; } 
.mytable tr:first-child:hover { color: green; } 
.mytable tr { color:blue; }
```

However if you are looking to specify any row, other than the `first-child`, you might have to look at some javascript, or maybe the use of `nth-child` but that would rule out < IE8 compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

.hoverstate:hover {
     color: green;
}

with HTML like this:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr class="hoverstate"><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

?